How to configure the angular-language-server in NvChad for a NX monorepo?
I'm trying to make the Angular language server work in NvChad, for a NX monorepo, but it doesn't seem to work. This is what I've pieced together from different sources on the internet:
-- EXAMPLE 
local on_attach = require("nvchad.configs.lspconfig").on_attach
local on_init = require("nvchad.configs.lspconfig").on_init
local capabilities = require("nvchad.configs.lspconfig").capabilities

local lspconfig = require "lspconfig"
local servers = { "html", "cssls" }

-- lsps with default config
for _, lsp in ipairs(servers) do
  lspconfig[lsp].setup {
    on_attach = on_attach,
    on_init = on_init,
    capabilities = capabilities,
  }
end

-- typescript
lspconfig.tsserver.setup {
  on_attach = on_attach,
  on_init = on_init,
  capabilities = capabilities,
}

-- **** vvv this is what I have added vvv ****
-- Angular
local util = require("lspconfig.util")

lspconfig.angularls.setup {
  on_attach = on_attach,
  on_init = on_init,
  capabilities = capabilities,

  -- as far as I understand, the line below (or something similar) is required because monorepos contain many app configuration files
  root_dir = util.root_pattern("project.json"),
}


Can someone provide a working configuration for NvChad that works for an NX monorepo containing Angular apps?
I'm unsure as to how to actually install the language server. I've installed it using Mason, where it's called "angular-language-server", but I've also seen sources stating that it should be installed using NPM (npm i .g @angular/language-server). I've done both.

I am completely new to NeoVim, so please be patient ☺️.

I had to uncomment this block of code in init.lua:
{
   "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
   config = function()
     require("nvchad.configs.lspconfig").defaults()
     require "configs.lspconfig"
   end,
},


